# Setting default date for Jqueryui datepicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple form for generating reports that I am adding a jqueryUI datepicker to. The problem I am having is when I try to repopulate the fields with the info from the user.

Jquery seems to be resetting the default value on my date fields (currently, it picks 2 different dates in July). How can I set it back to the user submitted value?

My current code:

```
<form method="post" action="">
        Username: <input type="text" size="12" name="username" required  value="foo" />
        Password: <input type="password" size="12" name="password" required value="bar" />
        Start Date: <input id="startdate" type="text" size="12" name="startday" required  value="06/28/2012" />
        End Date: <input id="enddate" type="text" size="12" name="endday" required  value="06/30/2012" />

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                $("#startdate").datepicker();
                $("#enddate").datepicker();
            });
        </script>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
```

Comment: RTFD - http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: @anonymousdownvotingislame I did. when that didn't work, I posted here.

Comment: Second sentence in my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11300671/144665).

Comment: I don't get it. What exactly is the problem? The code works OK, the date picker is initialized according to the `value` attribute and the "picked" date overwrites the pre-populated date. So what is the problem?

Comment: @SalmanA for some reason the datepicker is not initialized with the value attribute, but instead is overriding it with random dates in July

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the date to highlight on first opening if the field is blank. Specify either an actual date via a Date object or as a string in the current dateFormat, or a number of days from today (e.g. +7) or a string of values and periods ('y' for years, 'm' for months, 'w' for weeks, 'd' for days, e.g. '+1m +7d'), or null for today.

Initialize a datepicker with the defaultDate option specified.

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: +7 });
```

Get or set the defaultDate option, after init.

```
//getter
var defaultDate = $( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate" );

//setter
$( ".selector" ).datepicker( "option", "defaultDate", +7 );
```

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/iambriansreed/gMNrZ/

Comment: I tried this but it is not working: `$("#startdate").datepicker({ defaultDate: 06/26/2012 });`

Comment: @MrGlass Second sentence in my answer.

Comment: Did you, perhaps, want me to try this? `var d = new Date(06/26/12); $("#enddate").datepicker({ defaultDate: d });` still won't work.

Comment: sorry, `var d = new Date('06/26/12'); $("#enddate").datepicker({ defaultDate: d });` Valid date object, still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this while populating your date:

```
$( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "setDate" , date );
```

see [this](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#method-setDate)

Comment: tried this, did not work: `$("#startdate").datepicker( "setDate" , 06/16/2012 );`

Comment: try this before setting date.....    $( "#startdate" ).datepicker( "option", "dateFormat", "dd-mm-yyyy" );

Comment: anytime I use "setDate", date picker doesn't work at all. Also, your link is broken.

Comment: that link is not broken,,,,,you've to go down under that page to see methods tab.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-minDate

```
  var dateOptions = { 
  dateFormat: "mm/dd/yy", 
  constrainInput: true, 
  gotoCurrent: true, 
  minDate: new Date()
  };

  $('.date').datepicker(dateOptions);
```