# How to set yesterday date in DatePicker using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, datepicker

I'm having a textbox, when user click on it calender appears.This works fine,the calender showing the current date and previous date all are disable.But now i want to show calender with yesterday date selected.How can i achieve this.

for eg: if current date is `19-July-2012` then the calender must show date from `18-july-2012` and all other date before 18th must be inactive.how can I do that ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Duplicate question - you should search before you ask.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11300657/setting-default-date-for-jqueryui-datepicker

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Visit the documentation:
http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#option-defaultDate

```
$( ".yourselector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: -1, minDate:'-1d' });
```

Comment: thanks for replying,this works but i want for eg: if current date is 19-July-2012 then the calender must show date from 18-july-2012 and all other date before 18th must be inactive.how can i do that ?

Comment: I added the minDate as you want :). I have tested this now, and works

Comment: nice, didn't know that min date works with -1 as well. great comment.

Answer (score 4):

To have yesterday selected, you can do:

```
$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ defaultDate: -1 });
```

See http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate for the details.

Edit:

Based on the comment, the DatePicker should show dates from yesterday. So this requires a `minDate` of yesterday.

```
    $(".selector").datepicker({minDate: -1});
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/E3VEm/1/

Comment: thanks for replying,this works but i want for eg: if current date is 19-July-2012 then the calender must show date from 18-july-2012 and all other date before 18th must be inactive.how can i do that ?

Comment: I think this should work: `$( ".selector" ).datepicker({ minDate: -1) });` This will tell DatePicker to set the minimum selectable date 1 day before today. So all other days before that day will not be selectable.

Answer (score 1):

Check http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/ for all options.

You probably set the `minDate` somewhere to the date of today.

Comment: thanks for replying,this works but i want for eg: if current date is 19-July-2012 then the calender must show date from 18-july-2012 and all other date before 18th must be inactive.how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

Suggesting you are using jquery-ui datepicker:

```js
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({defaultDate: -1});
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/2qZRy/1/ for an example.

Comment: thanks for replying,this works but i want for eg: if current date is 19-July-2012 then the calender must show date from 18-july-2012 and all other date before 18th must be inactive.how can i do that ?

Answer (score 0):

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

This should work:

`$(".selector").datepicker({defaultDate: -1});`

Comment: @Archer, show me, from here have I copied it...
And why don't you tell that to anyone else who also answered this question? Or maybe you are waiting for some sort of a mini-flamewar?

Comment: You should not give something less sweary, and reportable.  Thanks for proving me correct.

Answer (score 0):

I think you achieve this using the defaultDate option.

http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#option-defaultDate

Comment: thanks for replying,this works but i want for eg: if current date is 19-July-2012 then the calender must show date from 18-july-2012 and all other date before 18th must be inactive.how can i do that ?